# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dumps'

Tags: json, python-3.7

I'm new to python, I try to serialize a list of custom object. this is the object I try to serialize:

```
test = [(deliveryRecipientObject){
           deliveryType = "selected"
           id = "gkfhgjhfjhgjghkj"
           type = "list"
       }]
```

After I read some post and tutorial I come up with this:

```
class deliverRecipientObject(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.deliveryType = ""
    self.id = ""
    self.type = ""

class MyJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, deliverRecipientObject):
            return {}
        return (MyJsonEncoder, self).dumps(obj)
```

then I run:

```
json.dumps(test, cls=MyJsonEncoder)
```

and then I got this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dumps'

my goal is to read that as json and then I can flatten it and save it as csv

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have intended `(MyJsonEncoder, self).dumps` to be `super(MyJsonEncoder, self).dumps`, though that would have been wrong too. Instead, you should be calling `super().default` (in python 3 you don't need to pass the arguments)

```
class MyJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, obj):
            if isinstance(obj, deliverRecipientObject):
                return {
                        "deliveryType": obj.deliveryType,
                        "id": obj.id,
                        "type": obj.type,
                       }
            return super().default(obj)
```

Comment: thank you for your info, however it doesn't work. I got back to where I started with the error said: 
TypeError: Object of type deliveryRecipientObject is not JSON serializable

Comment: With the above code, `json.dumps([deliverRecipientObject()], cls=MyJsonEncoder)` works for me.